# Customizable limit & sum symbols

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a way to define a *customizable* limit & sum operator. Currently I have strong/weak limits defined through

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\slim}{\mathfrak{s}-lim}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wlim}{\mathfrak{w}-lim}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\wslim}{\mathfrak{w*}-lim}
```

but I would like some more freedom, something like `$\lim[\mu]$` rendering as μ-lim with appropriate limits, and the same for sums (`$\sum[\mu]$` rendering as μ-Σ). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a possible realization, assuming that you are loading `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\plim}[1][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \def\next{\qopname\relax m{lim}}%
   \else
      \def\next{\qopname\newmcodes@ m{#1-lim}}%
   \fi
   \next
}

\newcommand*{\psum}[1][]{%
   \DOTSB
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
      \operatorname{#1-}\mkern-\thinmuskip
   \fi
   \sum@\slimits@
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\plim_{x\to0} \quad \plim[s]_{x\to0} \quad \plim[\mu]_{x\to0} \\[2ex]
\psum_i a_i \quad \psum[\mu]_i a_i
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have chosen the placing of the limits such that they are centered on the whole expression in case of the limit, but always only under the sum symbol (no matter what comes before).

Personally I think it's safer to use *new* macro names. Of course, nobody prevents you from changing the above code to

```
\renewcommand*{\lim}[1][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \def\next{\qopname\relax m{lim}}%
   \else
      \def\next{\qopname\newmcodes@ m{#1-lim}}%
   \fi
   \next
}

\renewcommand*{\sum}[1][]{%
   \DOTSB
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
      \operatorname{#1-}\mkern-\thinmuskip
   \fi
   \sum@\slimits@
}
```

Be aware that there might be drawbacks.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand{\plim}{o}{\operatorname*{\IfValueT{#1}{#1-}lim}}` is easier. `;-)` Similarly `\NewDocumentCommand{\psum}{o}{\DOTSB\operatorname{\IfValueT{#1}{#1-}}\!\sum}`

Comment: PS: If I wanted to define a "quick" command `\wsum` that is equivalent to `\psum[\mathfrak w]`, would `\DeclareMathOperator*{\wsum}{\csum[\mathfrak w]}` suffice?

Comment: @giobrach Just use `\newcommand`. No need for `\DeclareMathOperator` in this case.

Comment: @egreg If you knew how old my machine and my TeXlive distribution are...

Comment: Thanks again. You were very helpful

Comment: @campa Maybe the mu sigma would be better with a good negative \kern.

Comment: @projetmbc Yeah, I've thought of that too but it falls under "trivial adjustments" `:-)` Now I'm on smartphone, maybe later.

Answer (score 7):

Not to steal anything from campa's very fine answer, but there is room for  improvements to the proposed code.

If you want a generic way to prefix `\lim` and `\sum` and define commands in terms of the generic ones, an interface with `xparse` is easier.

I agree with campa that the limits should be centered below the whole “prefixed limit”, but only with respect to the big operator in case of `\sum` or similar cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\NewDocumentCommand{\prelim}{mm}{%
  \operatorname*{#1-{#2}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\preop}{mO{\thinmuskip}m}{%
  \DOTSB\operatorname{#1-}\mspace{-#2}#3%
}

\newcommand{\mulim}{\prelim{\mu}{\lim}}
\newcommand{\xlimsup}{\prelim{x}{\limsup}}

\newcommand{\musum}{\preop{\mu}[6mu]{\sum}}
\newcommand{\mubigcup}{\preop{\mu}{\bigcup}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\mulim_{x\to0} f(x) \\
\xlimsup_{x\to\infty} f(x) \\
\musum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \\
\mubigcup_{i\in I}A_i
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

I'd avoid redefining `\lim` and `\sum`. For the occasional non predefined operator, you can use `\prelim` and `\preop` with the suitable arguments. The `\preop` command has a middle optional argument that's used for improving the kerning between the prefix and the symbol, which is better with `\sum`, but not with `\bigcup`.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I ask myself why I bother to keep writing answers `:-D`

Comment: @campa As I said, your answer is very fine, worthy remaining and being the accepted one.

Comment: Thank you, @egreg. I would upvote, if I could (somehow the site won’t let me even though I’ve tried registering many times)!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the existing commands, and just redefine them to add an optional argument which adds a prefix.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\oldlim\lim
\let\oldsum\sum
\renewcommand*{\lim}[1][]{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\empty
        \oldlim%
    \else
        #1\text{--}\!\oldlim%
    \fi%
}
\renewcommand*{\sum}[1][]{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\empty
        \oldsum%
    \else
        #1\text{--}\!\!\oldsum%
    \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\(\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\) 
\(\lim[\mu]_{x\to 0} f(x)\)
\[
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)
\qquad
\lim[\mu]_{x\to 0} f(x)
\]

\(\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)\)
\(\sum[\mu]_{n=0}^\infty f(n)\)
\[
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)
\qquad
\sum[\mu]_{n=0}^\infty f(n)
\]
\end{document}
```

I adjusted the spacing to something that I thought looked good here, but it can easily be changed in the redefinitions of `\lim` and `\sum`.

Comment: Uhm, when the optional argument `#1` is given the formula starts with `#1` which in general is a `\mathord`. You lose the operator spacing in this case.

Comment: @Vincent Your mu limit is less pretty thatn the one of campa. But the API using an optional argument is a very good choice.